# body::before is in front - why?

Tags: css

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/wifayesole/2/edit?html,css

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://animaliaz-life.com/data_images/cat/cat8.jpg");
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}
body::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#body-container {
  background-color: white !important;
  height: 2000px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
header {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
nav {
  margin: 100px 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.nav > li > a > img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: auto !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.navbar-brand > img {
  height: 70px;
}
.icon-0 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.icon-1 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.icon-2 {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.icon-3 {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.icon-4 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.icon-5 {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}
.icon-6 {
  background-color: #34495e;
}
.icon-7 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <!--   NAVIGATION   -->


  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/vmp_logo_text_white.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


          <li class="normal dropdown">
            <a role="button" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="/test-1.html">
              <img class="icon-0" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/0.png" alt="Verein" />
              <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

              <li class="normal"><a href="/test-1/test-sub.html">test sub</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-2.html">
              <img class="icon-1" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/1.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-3.html">
              <img class="icon-2" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/2.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-4.html">
              <img class="icon-3" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/3.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-5.html">
              <img class="icon-4" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/4.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-6.html">
              <img class="icon-5" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/5.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test.html">
              <img class="icon-6" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/6.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->


    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<!--   CONTENT   -->
<div class="container" id="body-container">
  <div class="neos-contentcollection">
    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div>
        <p>This is the homepage</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--    FOOTER     -->
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <hr />

    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Problem 1: The colored overlay is behind the navigation but in front of the main content area.

My Solution: Set `z-index` to `bod::before`. But I think it's just a hack. How do I fix it?

Problem 2: If I remove the `border` from the `header` tag, I see that the `body::before` gets a `margin-top` kind of thing.

MySolution: Just add e.g. `margin-top: -100px;` or whatever to `body::before`. I think that would just make a wrong implementation overall work somehow, and is not good.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

If you edit the post and reshare it, please make sure to share a snapshot (option when you go on "share")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You may set `z-index:-1` to the pseudo.

The `body` `background` will be drawn in `HTML` `background`, so the `body:before`, will still stand on top of it and not anymore on top of body and its content.

---

Why does this work and pseudo doesn't get hidden ?

`body` is  `position:relative;` even without a `z-index`(so does `fixed` or `absolute` positionning), it comes up front any other element in the flux in `static` position, here the only other element is `HTML`. body children are positionned on/from same level of body .

> explanation about where bg is drawn : https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds
>
> ---

2)  for the header , you are seeing the collpsing margin effect in action.

> What is it ?, a classic confusing thing for beginners ;) see https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_CSS_layout_model_-_boxes_borders_margins_padding#Collapsing_margins

The border (can be transparent) or a padding is a way to contain it inside and not let it be applied on the outside.

---

**snippet below with `z-index` and `padding` instead `border`. these are not hacks, but features.**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://animaliaz-life.com/data_images/cat/cat8.jpg");
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}
body::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#body-container {
  background-color: white ;
  
    
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;

}
header {
  padding:1px;

}
nav {
  margin: 100px 0px !important;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.nav > li > a > img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
  height: auto !important;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.navbar-brand > img {
  height: 70px;
}
.icon-0 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.icon-1 {
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.icon-2 {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}
.icon-3 {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}
.icon-4 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.icon-5 {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}
.icon-6 {
  background-color: #34495e;
}
.icon-7 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <!--   NAVIGATION   -->


  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/vmp_logo_text_white.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>


      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


          <li class="normal dropdown">
            <a role="button" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="/test-1.html">
              <img class="icon-0" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/0.png" alt="Verein" />
              <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

              <li class="normal"><a href="/test-1/test-sub.html">test sub</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-2.html">
              <img class="icon-1" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/1.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-3.html">
              <img class="icon-2" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/2.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-4.html">
              <img class="icon-3" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/3.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-5.html">
              <img class="icon-4" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/4.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test-6.html">
              <img class="icon-5" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/5.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>



          <li class="normal">
            <a href="/test.html">
              <img class="icon-6" src="/_Resources/Static/Packages/VMP.Website/Images/Nav/White/6.png" alt="Verein" />
            </a>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->


    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<!--   CONTENT   -->
<div class="container" id="body-container">
  <div class="neos-contentcollection">
    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div>
        <p>This is the homepage</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--    FOOTER     -->
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <hr />

    <div class=" typo3-neos-nodetypes-text">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: so should I add e.g. header { border: 1px solid transparent; } or what? Isn't there a "proper" solution?

Comment: @xotix yrs, this the way

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any z-index, positioned elements (and pseudo elements) always are displayed on top of not-positioned ones.

So yes, the solution is to apply z-index. Not hackish at all.

As to problem 2, just use `left` and `top` for the absolutely positioned stuff.